# didSelectRowAtIndexPath does not work when uitableview datasource is filtered

Tags: iphone, uitableview

i have uitableview and a search bar with searchDisplayController, i fill tableview datasource with data from database and i user search bar for searching, at a time uitableview datasource is not filtered the didSelectRowAtIndexPath works fine and it goes to the detailviewcontroller, but when i use search and filter datasource then if i select a cell the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method does not fire.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    KardexViewController* kardexViewController = [[KardexViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:kardexViewController animated:YES];
}
```

this is how i add uisearchbar

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    dataSource = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    self.navigationItem.title = Title;

    searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];

    searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
    searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
    searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar; 
}
```

and how i filter datasource

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    NSMutableArray* result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < [self.allData count]; i++) {
        NSRange range = [[[self.allData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Code"] rangeOfString:searchString];

        if(range.length > 0)
            [result addObject:[self.allData objectAtIndex:i]];

        range = [[[self.allData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Name"] rangeOfString:searchString];

        if(range.length > 0)
            [result addObject:[self.allData objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

    self.dataSource  = [result copy];
    [result release];
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];

    return YES;
}

-(void) searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
    self.dataSource  = [self.allData copy];
}
```

So Thanks inadvance

Comment: please provide code for how you use search and filer the table in it there will some problem and so it does not work properly or at all

Answer (score 17, accepted):

after some search i found that i just should set one thing more

```
searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
```

Comment: Thanks for coming back and answering your own question.  I had scratched my head for some time working this out thinking searchDisplayController.delegate = self; was enough, it wasn't, I needed to add your code and now all is well.

Comment: @Ali, UISearchDisplayController is deprecated in iOS 8. What is the solutions now? Can you please share with me.

Comment: @NarasimhaNallamsetty I am sorry, it is a long time I haven't work on native mobile app.